# Map and splice gives empty instead of nothing

Tags: javascript

I have an algorithm :

```js
let someArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let mapped = someArray.map(number => {
    let index = someArray.indexOf(5)
    if (index !== -1) {
        someArray.splice(index, 1)
    }
    console.log(typeof number)
    return number
})
console.log(mapped)
console.log(mapped.length)
console.log(Object.keys(mapped).length)
```

So what I expected to have  was `mapped=[1,2,3,4]` and `mapped.length=4`

But instead I have `mapped=[1,2,3,4,empty]` and `mapped.length=5`.

So what I thought is : in the beginning, map is going for 5 iterations so it does it no matter what. That's why I added `console.log(typeof number)`.

But it's executed only  4 times.

I know to have my expected result, filter is way better. I'm just wondering, what is happening here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values, including undefined. It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).
>
> If existing elements of the array are changed, their value as passed to callback will be the value at the time map visits them. Elements that are deleted after the call to map begins and before being visited are not visited.

You're mutating the array as you're iterating over it, which means that once index [4] is reached, that element (whose value used to be 5) doesn't exist anymore, which means the function does not get called on that iteration, resulting in `<empty>`. The resulting array is created with 5 elements, but the callback is never called on the last element.

Use `filter` instead.